# Differentiating between 'personal' facebook API key and 'Business Page' API keys

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, facebook-access-token

I am building a website and want to transfer over the data of a business Facebook page (posts) and put it into a 'social wall' so to speak on the website, using the Facebook API. The problem that I am having is that it is copying the data from my own personal Facebook account, rather than the Facebook 'business pages' account. I can't seem to change it!

How can I make the Facebook API differentiate between my 'personal' facebook API key and the 'Business Page' API key, and thereby transfer the data from the business page rather than my personal page?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what you're trying to do is use FB API to get post from a FB page and then display that into a website. After that, I guess you're planning to allow comments and some kind of interaction from there.

The issue you're facing is likely that when you use the API, you're getting back posts from your personal account instead of the page you want.

If so, the problem is the access token you're using.

To work with FB Graph API, you need an access token for every request, the access token will identify the person making the call.

You can learn more about access tokens here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

That said, I think there might be two different issues here:

1. You're calling me/posts using your user access token. That will get you back your own posts.
2. You're calling [your_user_name]/posts with a page access token, That will also give you your own posts.

You can see page posts that are public using your own access token and for the rest, you need a page access token.

If you're admin of the page, you can query me/accounts and you'll get the page access token for your page. If not, you'll need to go to business manager and get it from there.

If non of these options are available for you is because you have no access to this FB Page and therefore, you're not allowed to do this.